# Number of solutions of a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to find the solution to a homogenous differential equation of 2rd order. For that I use DSolve[]. What I get is a single expression, which should be the solution. But I am asked to find all the solutions of it. Is there a way in Mathematica to find all the solutions and not simplify all of them into one general solution?

My equation is:

f''[x] - (2*(2*x^2 - 1))/(x*(x^2 - 1))*f'[x] + (4/(x^2 - 1))*f[x] =
HPL[{4}, x]/(x*(1 - x)*(1 + x))

I do:

```
DSolve[f''[x] - (2*(2*x^2 - 1))/(x*(x^2 - 1))*
f'[x] + (4/(x^2 - 1))f[x] == 0, f[x], x]
```

The result is:

```
    {{f[x] -> 
   C[2] + 1/
     15 (x^2 (-24 + 18 x^2 + 5 x C[1] - 3 x^3 C[1]) + 
       3 (2 - 5 x^3 + 3 x^5) Log[1 - x] + (6 + 15 x^3 - 9 x^5) Log[
         1 + x])}}
```

I have one solution, but since this is a differential equation of order 2, I need two solutions. How can I do that?

Comment: There are infinite many solutions depending on the C[i], however, only 3 at a time can be independent. You can pick out solutions by specifying initial values.

Comment: Why do you have `f'[3]` in there? The ode is of degree 1. Why do you expect more than one general solution? **since this is a differential equation of order 3,** the order is 2, not 3.

Comment: @Nasser it was a typo.  I edit and fixed it

Comment: @DanielHuber And If I do not have initial values and I am trying to execute the following equation, so that I find the particular solution: $$f_p(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n f_{h,i}(x)\int \frac{g(y)W_i(y)}{W(y)}$$ how do I proceed ?

Comment: with your update, can not run the code any more since there is no `HPL`. Also you have `=` and `==` in the same equation.

Comment: @Nasser Here is where I took the package: https://www.physik.uzh.ch/data/HPL/ (HPL-2.0.tar.gz) and with the following command I use it: $HPLPath = "C:\\Users\\dari_\\Desktop\\Mathematica\\Vorlesung \
3\\HPL"; $Path = Flatten[{$Path, $HPLPath}];
<< HPL`;

Comment: We are losing the the thread here. Lets go back. The ode is of order 2 not 3. Why do you keep saying the order is 3? The ode is of degree 1. So one general solution is expected. I have no idea why you think there there should be more than one general solution or the number of general solutions should be the same as the ode order? So you are saying `DSolve[y''[x] == 0, y[x], x]` should have 2 general solutions and not one? I am just trying to understand your question. No need for HPL package to answer this.

Comment: You are correct about everything. Ultimately, regardless of the order of the differential equation or whether it's homogenous or not, you have one general solution. But in my exercise, in order to find the particular solution,  I need to apply the above written formula, which as you can see it has the terms $f_{h,i}(x)$ which are solutions of the hom. differential, and we have as many as the order of the differential equation. That's why I need to have for this eq. two solutions, which I can use in the expression above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142249/discussion-between-imbaf-and-nasser).

Comment: Then you mean you are looking for the BASIS solutions. Not the general solution. ode of order 2 will have two linearly independent BASIS solutions. Think of it as vector space with 2 dimensions. The general solution is linear combination of the BASIS solutions. These BASIS solutions come from the  solution of the homog. part of the ode. You can extract them by collecting on each constant of integration, The formula you have looks like the Variation of Parameters formula to find the particular solution, which requires knowing the BASIS solutions of the homog. part.

Comment: I'll try to write something for the example you have if no answer shows up as I have to go now.

Comment: @Nasser exactly! I am fully aware of the theory as to how one solves different types of differential/partial differential equations, whether coupled or not. But I don't know how can I in mathematica find, what you call the Basic solutions, which then later on, can be used to have the general solution.

Comment: There are many ways to construct a basis from the general solution `dsol` to the homogeneous equation. (1) `basis = D[f[x] /. dsol // First, {{C[1], C[2]}}]`. (2) `basis = dsol /. {{C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 0}, {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 1}}`. (3) Solve two homogeneous IVPs with linearly independent ICs (seems inadvisable in this case, however).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First obtain the homog. solution in order to extract the basis functions $f_1,f_2$

```
odeHomog =   f''[x] - (2*(2*x^2 - 1))/(x*(x^2 - 1))*f'[x] + (4/(x^2 - 1)) f[x];
forcingFunction = x;
solH = DSolveValue[odeHomog == 0, f[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f1 = First@Cases[solH, any_*C[1] :> any]
f2 = First@Cases[solH, any_*C[2] :> any]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now that we know the basis solution, find Wronskian

```
wronskian = Det[{{f1, f2}, {D[f1, x], D[f2, x]}}] // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Find particular solution using the *variation of parameters* formula. The forcing function is $f(x)=x$ in this example. The formula is

[image]

```
yp=-f1*Integrate[f2*forcingFunction/wronskian,x]+f2*Integrate[f1*forcingFunction/wronskian,x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Add this to the homog. solution to find the general solution

```
 yg = C[1]*f1 + C[2]*f2 + yp
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Verify against Mathematica's

```
 solbyMMA = DSolveValue[odeHomog == forcingFunction, f[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 solbyMMA == yg // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you! While I knew the theory, I didn't know how to implement it in mathematica. I have one question regarding your solution. How was mathematica able to solve the problem, meaning find the particular solution, once you substitute $g(y)$ (in the formula) with $PolyLog[4,x] = HPL[{4},x],$ without any Partial fraction decomposition. Because we need to simplify it, so that mathematica can solve it.

Comment: @imbAF  **How was mathematica able to solve the problem** I assume Mathematica also uses variation of parameters to find particular solutions (unless it detects undetermined coefficients can be used, which is not always the case). As for the rest of your question. I am sorry, I do not follow it. I do not know what HPL[4,x] is. I am using the ode you posted above. But may be someone else will have an idea and answer that part.

Comment: $HPL[4,X]=Li_4(x)$ where i.e $Li_2(x)=-\int_0^x \frac{ln(1-x')}{x'}dx'$ and in general $Li_n(x)=\int_0^x \frac{Li_{n-1}(x')}{x'}dx'$. But thanks once again.

Comment: I am trying to implement your code, but I get the following error: "DSolveValue::deqx: Supplied equations are not differential or integral equations of the given functions."

Comment: @imbAF you must have some error in input. Can you post complete code you used? looks like you used different dependent variable in the call to DSolve than the one in the ode itself

Comment: odehomog = 
  f''[x] - (2*(2*x^2 - 1))/(x*(x^2 - 1))*f'[x] + (4/(x^2 - 1))*f[x];

solH = DSolveValue[odehomog == 0, f[x], x]

f1 = First@Cases[solH, any_*C[1] :> any]
f2 = First@Cases[solH, any_*C[2] :> any]

Comment: It works now. I had made an error mistake